# Word Vba: Get position of the first table borderline

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing some code in VBA in word and I would like to get the position of first borderline of the table as shown in this image
[image]

As seen in the above image, i would like to equalize the first table margin and second table margin (not sure if "margin" is the right word). The intention is to make the first table and second table column widths equal and combine them, merging them into one table. The word document has about 20 separate table and hence i would like to combine all of them into one single table. Please note that the empty tables that you see above has data removed to preserve confidential information.

What I have tried so far:

```
Public Sub CorrectTables()
    Dim mainTable As Table
    Dim secondTable As Table
    
    Dim firstColWidth As Integer
    Dim secondColumnWidth As Integer
    Dim thirdColumnWidth As Integer
    Dim fourthColumnWidth As Integer
    Dim fiftColumnWidth As Integer

    'Get current table
    Set mainTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    
    **firstColMarginPos = mainTable.LeftPadding** This is where i need some help to set the position
    firstColWidth = mainTable.Columns(1).Width
    secondColumnWidth = mainTable.Columns(2).Width
    thirdColumnWidth = mainTable.Columns(3).Width
    fourthColumnWidth = mainTable.Columns(4).Width
    fiftColumnWidth = mainTable.Columns(5).Width
    
    Dim currentTableCount As Integer
    
    While ActiveDocument.Tables.Count <> 1
        currentTableCount = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
        Set secondTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)
        secondTable.LeftPadding = firstColMarginPos
        secondTable.Columns(1).Width = firstColWidth
        secondTable.Columns(2).Width = secondColumnWidth
        secondTable.Columns(3).Width = thirdColumnWidth
        secondTable.Columns(4).Width = fourthColumnWidth
        secondTable.Columns(5).Width = fiftColumnWidth
        
        Selection.Tables(1).Select
        Selection.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        
        While (ActiveDocument.Tables.Count - currentTableCount = 0)
            Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Wend
    Wend
    
    
    
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. For the first table, i am able to get the indentation:

```
firstColMarginPos = mainTable.Rows.LeftIndent
```

Then i am able to use it to set the value for the second table:

```
secondTable.Rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=firstColMarginPos, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustFirstColumn
```